# Google's Translation API (REST) and PHP

Tags: php, rest

I want to translate words that has been send to the server from the client side. According to the documentation from Google you can use as follow:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=INSERT-YOUR-KEY&source=en&target=de&q=Hello%20world
```

and it will respond with the following JSON object:

```
{
    "data": {
        "translations": [
            {
                "translatedText": "Hallo Welt"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I use the following in php:

```
$data = file_get_contents('https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=KEY8&source=en&target=ru&q='.$to_be_translated);
$data = json_decode($data);
$translated = $data->translations->translatedText;
```

This does not work but if I use their JS example, then I do get the required result, therefore the translation setup is fine, the problem must be in my PHP script.

I also tried:

```
$data = $_GET['https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=KEY8&source=en&target=ru&q='.$to_be_translated];
```

but to no avail. Any suggestions?

Comment: it what way does it not work? Do you get an error message?

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/source/browse/trunk/examples/translate/simple.php

Comment: The $translated variable is empty.

Comment: What is in $to_be_translated?

Comment: "What is in $to_be_translated?" This is the string that php receives and what I want to translate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest:

```
$request = 'https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=KEY8&source=en&target=ru&q='.$to_be_translated;

var_dump($request);
```

Copy the string, beginning with "https", returned from this var_dump, and place it into a new web browser window... what do you get back in your browser?  If it looks valid, then move on to the next step. If it does not work, you are assembling your $request wrong.

```
$response = file_get_contents($request);

var_dump($response);
```

What does $response look like? An error? Or does it look like valid JSON? If its valid JSON...

```
$data = json_decode($response);

var_dump($data);
```

What does $data look like here? Good? Any JSON parsing exceptions?

```
$translated = $data->translations->translatedText;

var_dump($translated);
```

And what does $translated look like?

Comment: Thanks, I followed this and it give the right output up till after  `$data = json_decode($response);` and the var_dump looks as follow: `object(stdClass)#1 (1) { ["data"]=> object(stdClass)#2 (1) { ["translations"]=> array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#3 (1) { ["translatedText"]=> string(5) "toets" } } } }`, which is the right translation but after `$translated = $data->translations->translatedText;` it gives an output of NULL. I tried `$translated = $data->translations[0]->translatedText;` but still the same. So, it seems that $data is fine but how do I get the translated text out of it?

Comment: Please post the output of serialize($data)

Comment: It is: `string(132) "O:8:"stdClass":1:{s:4:"data";O:8:"stdClass":1:{s:12:"translations";a:1:{i:0;O:8:"stdClass":1:{s:14:"translatedText";s:5:"toets";}}}}"`

Comment: It seems that using arrays is doing the trick: I used `$data = json_decode($response, true);` and when doing the following, I get the translation: `$translated = $data['data']['translations'][0]['translatedText'];`  I think I will stick with this but going through this approach helped me to get to this point.

Comment: Great! Although there are only 3 lines of code, a lot can go wrong at each line -- so inserting some sort of debug statements in between is the best way to troubleshoot these sorts of things. I would also recommend an IDE that supports debugging, it makes it even quicker and faster to debug if its builtin to your development environment.